# Run update statement on inserted rows only through a trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, insert

I have created a Trigger to update a custom date `[Invoice.ContractStartDate]` on an invoice record when added to the Invoice Table `[InvoiceTable]`.

The Trigger below works but I would like this to run for **Inserted records only** and avoid using the WHERE clause for DateTimeCreated.

I will still require the `WHERE` clause for `Contract.Days <> ' '`

Is this possible using using `AFTER INSERT` or `INSTEAD OF INSERT`?

```
 CREATE TRIGGER UpdateContractStartDate ON InvoiceTable 
 FOR INSERT AS
 UPDATE InvoiceTable
 SET InvoiceTable.ContractStartDate = InvoiceTable.InvoiceDate + Contract.Days
 FROM Contract
 INNER JOIN InvoiceTable
     ON InvoiceTable.ContractID = Contract.ContractID
 WHERE (CAST(InvoiceTable.DateTimeCreated AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
 AND (Contract.Days <> '')
```

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide any information on your table schema, but assuming you have a unique key "Id"

The typical syntax would be

```
Update it set
  it.ContractStartDate = it.InvoiceDate + c.Days
from inserted i
join InvoiceTable it on it.Id=i.Id
join Contract c on c.ContactId=it.ContractId and c.Days <> ''
```